# Why does my query work in my VM dev environment but not in production/online?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a relatively simple set up for products and reviews. Here are the relevant parts of my Models:

Product

```
public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }
```

Review

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
```

In my controller, I grab the product:

```
$product = Product::find($id);
```

Then I grab the reviews:

```
$reviews = $product->reviews()->get()
```

This works fine in my VM dev environment, but when I upload it to my live site it doesn't work. If I try and access $product->reviews in Tinker, I get a 'call to undefined method` error. I have uploaded all the model files and added the relevant tables to the database. I can directly access the Reviews with

```
$reviews = App\Reviews::all()
```

I just can't access them via the product. What gives?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access reviews on product via

```
$product = Product::with('reviews')->where('id', $id)->get();

// then use the reviews
$reviews = $product->reviews;
```